# put values in Hashmap in Groovy using loops

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap, maps

I have to store some values in Hashmap, using loops. I tried using .put(key,value) method, it worked but in loop the Hashmap gets overwritten by new values, is there any method to not overwrite the new values?
Here is my code :-

```
import javax.sound.sampled.Line
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
String map
for (String id : ids) {
    map =  displayTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id))
    String mapValue = map.split(" ")
    String value = mapValue.split(",")[1].trim().replace("]","")
    String key = mapValue.split(",")[0].replace("[(","").replace(")","")
    timeZones.put(key,value)
    println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    println(timeZones)
}
```

Comment: What is `displayTimeZone`?

Comment: displyTimeZone is a method to get All the TimeZone Ids. The method returns values like this :-
(GMT-7:420) America/Hermosillo
(GMT-5:300) America/Indiana/Indianapolis
(GMT-6:360) America/Indiana/Knox
(GMT-5:300) America/Indiana/Marengo
(GMT-5:300) America/Indiana/Petersburg
(GMT-6:360) America/Indiana/Tell_City(GMT-9:540) America/Juneau
(GMT-5:300) America/Kentucky/Louisville
(GMT-5:300) America/Kentucky/Monticello
 and so on for all regions TimeZone Ids.

Comment: Any chance you can update the example so we can run it, and see the problem you're describing?

Comment: If old values are overridden by new, this means, that you are storing them under the same key.